# Which frameworks have initializer or starter?

Tags: frameworks, code-generation

Spring initializer, Steeltoe Initializer, laravel initializer ... all of these solutions are web based tools to generate personalized framework structure. Is there other frameworks that offers similar solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java ecosystem, **Micronaut** and **Quarkus** have each a basic initializer :

- https://micronaut.io/launch/
- https://code.quarkus.io/